# Nodejs eventloop when sending an email

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I am relatively new to Nodejs and have been using the Express framework to build a web application. In the application, I create a receipt after someone successfully pays for an item, and I want to email them the receipt.

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking after a user does the post to the /payment I could reroute them to an endpoint that emails the email and then reroute them again to the /receipt to show the receipt. Or I could do this within the /payment, but will that block anything and make it slower, the checkout using Stripe and adding everything to the database already takes a few seconds.

I do not completely understand the whole eventloop concept even though I have read a lot about it. I understand callbacks and all of that, but am not sure why that does not block the eventloop? Can callbacks be executed at the same time as other functions? I think that will help me understand the best course of action for sending an email, depending on if that will block anything and make it even more delayed. Thanks for all the help, appreciate anyone out there that can help a beginner like myself understand these super important Node concepts. Thanks.

Comment: `at the same time` no javascript runs "at the same time" as other javascript

Comment: Okay I read your profile and you look like you know your stuff. I looked into it a little more and from my understanding this is what happens: when a function is called it is pushed onto the stack (which is executed by V8 engine). In the meantime, the callbacks are put into the task queue and when the stack is empty the eventloop passes the callbacks into the stack to be executed. If this is wrong please correct me. Otherwise, if this is correct how is that beneficial? If you run functions that take long time and then when they're done execute the callbacks, how is that any faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide much insights about your web application but here I mentioned some points which is very important for any beginner in Node.js to understand.

- Node.js come up the event driven programming concept, as only one
  single thread is working for accepting the client connections and
  keeping track of callbacks (maybe within a call stack for say).
- But the fact is Node.js is not implemented with a single thread. Whenever a http connection comes into the picture, 4 threads is automatically got assigned for any cpu bound operation associated with it.
- Generally, all i/o bound operation have callbacks associated with it. Hence, a main loop keeps waiting for the events (like for say completion of i/o bound operation eg. *end of reading a file*) and a callback is triggered by this loop whenever any such kind of event is detected. Now, this main thread take care of this callback.
- Though callbacks and events seems to be quite similiar to each other but there is thin difference i.e. 
  callbacks are called with the result of asynchronous function like that of the code below

```js
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, data) {
   if (err) return console.error(err);
   console.log(data.toString());
});

console.log("Program Ended");
```

*But event loop is actually looking for any event to happen not for results for all the cases like that of callbacks. Event maybe like opening a file or closing of file. A common use case of event is given below:*

```
    // Import events module
var events = require('events');


// Create an eventEmitter object
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

// Create an event handler as follows
var connectHandler = function connected() {
   console.log('connection succesful.');

   // Fire the data_received event 
   eventEmitter.emit('data_received');
}

// Bind the connection event with the handler
eventEmitter.on('connection', connectHandler);

// Bind the data_received event with the anonymous function
eventEmitter.on('data_received', function(){
   console.log('data received succesfully.');
});

// Fire the connection event 
eventEmitter.emit('connection');

console.log("Program Ended.");
```

For detailed description of above points go through Node.js documentation once more.

Comment: So do I have this right: there is a main loop waiting for events to happen, like a GET request or something like that. And then once that happens there is another thread that executes the code within that while the eventloop keeps waiting for other events? Yes, sorry about the vagueness of the web application. I essentially need to send an email after a user purchases something, so if I had a function that I run within the POST request would that be fine? If my above explanation is correct, which I am not sure it is, than I would assume yes. Thanks for your help!